Smart card certificate used for authentication was not trusted - Windows Server
New to testing smart card authentication in Windows domain environment
I followed Yubikey's guide to allow smart cards to be used for login in Windows server. I also did the self enrollment option so clients can enroll themselves for the smart key cert option.
At first, it says the revocation server was offline (during the enrollment) however, this is because in my CDP (CRL Distribution Point) I did not put a server address that clients could retrieve the crl list. Once I did that (it is accessible from every client and downloadable) and resolvable then it allowed me to enroll a certificate.
However, when I try to login back again using a smart card, it says "The Smart card certificate used for authentication was not trusted"
I checked my event logs, specifically security and CAPI2 but nothing correspond with the specific smart card login. I thought I had to manually add the certificate from issued certs to the computer certificates and user certificates, but it still didnt work. Did I miss some configurations or something?
#Edit 1
I'm using a two-tier PKI Hierarchy. Roughly using this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831348(v=ws.11)

I thought I had to manually add the certificate from issued certs to the computer certificates and user certificates. No. The CA certificate needs to be in the appropriate stores on the endpoints and the DC. What steps have you performed to do that?

Are you referring to the root CA? If that's the case, then it was already added on the endpoints and the DC under the trusted root CA. I was referring to the user's certificate in the issued certificate that was created when I enrolled the smartcard.

The smart card certificate never needs to be copied anywhere. The CAPI2 event log should have the details on the offender certificate.  Tell us what happened when you ran certutil with the scroots switch.

Have you read/followed this Microsoft article?

Additionally, in Windows, smartcard successfully checking the CDP is optional. This can be disabled, which would simplify the scenario a bit. It is common to not have a mandatory CRL check if the smartcards need to function in a disaster recovery environment. Otherwise you would be screwed.

It seems to be a revocation checking issue according to the link in the microsoft article. The CAPI2 event logs also has some errors for verify revocation (but there are also some that has no errors) certutil -scroots view seems to be ok with the rootCA showing up and -scinfo some parts show The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate. 0x80092012 (-2146885614 CRYPT_E_NO_REVOCATION_CHECK) ------------------------------------ Revocation check skipped -- no revocation information available

"It is common to not have a mandatory CRL check if the smartcards need to function in a disaster recovery environment. Otherwise you would be screwed."

Did you check to see if the CRL it is complaining about is accessible?

Got it to work. The offline root CA is supposed to have a CDP configured so that the subordinate CA has a CDP. This is required as stated in the Microsoft website

Every CA Certificate except the root CA in the certificate chain contains a valid CDP extension in the certificate.

What I did was, I added a CDP in the root CA that points to the IIS server folder of the subordinate CA. Something like this http://app1.test.local/pki/<CaName><CRLNameSuffix>.crl
Then, I published the CRL by going to certsrv>Revoked Certificate>right click All task>publish. Then I take the newly published CRL files (two of them) which by default should be located in C:\Windows\System32\CertSrv\CertEnroll and transferred them over manually to the subordinate CA pki folder which is hosted on the IIS
Then you can keep your root CA offline until the next CRL update. You could set the CRL next update time longer than a year if your subordinate CA doesn't change.
Thanks @GregAskew and @garethTheRed for the link. It was helpful.
